# i want to fetch same template in cntroller

Tags: html, codeigniter, templates

```
my index controller this and showing good html and header and footer is working correct but when i want to add method the css and html not working .
    public function index()
   {
$data['clients_list'] = $this->clients_model->get_all_clients();
 $this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('clients/index', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
   }
```

this is  my add method where i want to add html as header and footer

```
  public function add()
     {
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('clients/add');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

Comment: do you have add.php? inside .../views/clients/.And also you are not sending any data at your add view. and your add.php should have same html structure like index.php view.hope you undrestand

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using $this->load->view() is not supported in the framework. You should only be loading one view. If you wish to include multiple views within a single view you must save them within the data to be rendered in the master view and echo them out within that view. To do this you use the third parameter of the view function explained at the codeigniter api: [Very bottom of page](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)

An example of this would be:

Controller:

```
function index(){
    $data['clients_list'] = $this->clients_model->get_all_clients();
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view('template/header', $data, TRUE);
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('template/footer', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('clients/index', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $header; ?>

<!-- YOUR INDEX PAGE CONTENT-->

<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

The third parameter of view() tells the framework to pre-render the view and output the contents as a string value which allows you to save as a variable and echo into the primary page.

Phil Sturgeon wrote a wonderful template library that I have been using in my projects that allows for a webforms style "master page" that you can have the rest of your views rendered inside of so that you do not have to build your header/footer view each time and inject it into every view.
[Phil Sturgeon Template Library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-template)